# Showing a sum in a field of fractions is nonzero

Tags: field-theory, solution-verification, polynomial-rings

Let $k$ be a field, let $c_1, \ldots, c_m \in k$ be distinct elements, and let $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m$ be nonzero elements of $k$. Prove that
$$\frac{\lambda_1}{x - c_1} + \cdots + \frac{\lambda_m}{x - c_m} \neq 0.$$

**ATTEMPT**

Suppose that the sum is 0. Then multiplying both sides by the common denominator the product $(x - c_1) \cdots (x - c_m)$ yields
$$\lambda_1[(x - c_2) \cdots (x - c_m)] + \cdots + \lambda_m[(x - c_1) \cdots (x - c_{m - 1})] = 0. $$
Since the $\lambda_i$ are nonzero, this implies that the set of $m$ polynomials
$$\{(x - c_2) \cdots (x - c_m), \ldots, (x - c_1) \cdots (x - c_{m - 1})\}$$
are linearly dependent over $k$. This means that any basis for $k[x]$ has at most $m$ elements. But this is a contradiction because $k[x]$ has no finite basis (there are polynomials of arbitrarily high degree). Therefore the original sum is 0.

Comment: There is a big jump at "This means that any basis for k[x] has at most m elements." Also, why did the $x$ get subscripts? I think you start off right. Try plugging in $x = c_m$ to your first equation (after you get rid of the unnecessary subscripts on the $x$).

Comment: There is a typo in your question as I don’t understand why you ended up with $x_i$ while you only have one variable $x$ namely. See answer below by the way.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt You are right. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence « *This means that any basis for $k[x]$ has at most $m$ elements.* » is wrong. That would be true if those polynomials would span $k[x]$.

To get the desired result, replace $x$ by $c_i$ in the equality

$$\lambda_1[(x- c_2) \cdots (x- c_m)] + \cdots + \lambda_m[(x - c_1) \cdots (x - c_{m - 1})] = 0 $$ to get $\lambda_i =0$ as the $c_i$ are supposed to be distinct and $k$ a field, thus without zero divisors.

A contradiction as the $\lambda_i $ are supposed to be nonzero.